# Two unusual approximations in right triangle trigonometry

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, taylor-expansion, approximation, approximation-theory

iN the 1780 textbook The Resolution of Triangles, by Hugh Worthington’s, the following approximation to solve the case of a right triangle when the angles and one side is given:

> (1) "In any right angled triangle, as $ CAB$, let $ \alpha$ be the lesser angle in degrees. Then $\frac{57.3}{\alpha} + \frac{3\alpha}{1000} : 1 = AC : AB$, nearly"

where $AC$ and $AB$ are the hypotenuse and the opposite side to the angle $\alpha$, respectively. Also,

> (2) $ 1 : 1 - \frac{1\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2}{10000} = AC : BC $

where $BC$ is the adjacent side.

The question is: how to derive the approximations (1) and (2)? The numerator of the first fraction in (1) is $57.3$. It should be related to $180/\pi \approx 57.29...$

Comment: Even though this is probably not how it was done at the time, it would still probably help to recast everything in modern language. Namely the first approximation is supposed to be an estimate for $\csc(\pi \alpha/180)$ for $0 \leq \alpha \leq 45$ and the second is supposed to be an estimate for $\tan(\pi \alpha/180)$ under the same assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Using $\frac{180}{\pi}$ for $57.3$, rewriting (1) so that $\alpha$ is in radians, and noting that $AC:AB = \csc \alpha$, one gets
$$\frac{3 \left(\pi  \left(60000+\frac{180 \alpha }{\pi }\right)^2\right)}{1000\pi\cdot\frac{ 180 \alpha }{\pi }} = \frac{1}{\alpha} + \frac{27}{50\pi}\alpha.$$
The MacLaurin series for $\csc\alpha$ is
$$\frac{1}{\alpha }+\frac{\alpha }{6}+\frac{7 \alpha ^3}{360}+\frac{31 \alpha ^5}{15120}+\frac{127 \alpha ^7}{604800}+\frac{73 \alpha ^9}{3421440}+O\left(\alpha ^{11}\right),$$
and $\frac{1}{6} \approx 0.1666667$ while $\frac{27}{50\pi}\approx 0.171887$.

Note that just $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ is a pretty good approximation for $\alpha$ small. Since $\alpha$ is the smaller angle, it should be a decent approximation all by itself. In the graph below, $\csc\alpha$ is the blue line, the approximation in (1) is the orange line, $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ the green line, and $\frac{27}{50\pi}\alpha$ the red line.
[image]

The second equation is similar; rewriting for $\alpha$ in radians and looking at the Maclaurin series of the resulting LHS and of $\sec\alpha$ shows that the first two terms are pretty close to each other.

Comment: You have a typo: you wrote $\frac{27}{50\pi}$ instead of $\frac{27}{50\pi} \alpha$ in the paragraph above the graph.

Comment: @Ian Thanks, fixed.